# paste0 regular and italicized text in R

Tags: r, string, format, concatenation

I need to concatenate two strings within an R object: one is just regular text; the other is italicized. So, I tried a lot of combinations, e.g.

```
paste0(" This is Regular", italic( This is Italics))
```

The desired result should be:

This is Regular *This is Italics*

Any ideia on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no `italic` function in base R.  `paste0` and other R functions return `character`s.  They have no concept of format, such as Italics or bold.  Format is a characteristic of output destination.  So  the way to get Italic text would depend on your output destination.  It can't be done in a text file or a .Rda file.  It can be done (in different ways) for a PDF, Markdown or HTML file, to give just a few examples.

Comment: italic's and other mathimatical annotations are used in plots. E.g. `plot(iris$Species, main = expression(paste("This is Regular ", italic(" This is Italics"))))` will return a simple plot with the title in regular and italics. Search on SO for examples and read the help (`?italic`) with the italic function.

Comment: Thanks @Limey... So for HTML how can I format text from a paste0 expression?

Comment: Thanks @phiver... I know how to do it for plots... but I need a italic in a regular HTML page

Answer (score 1):

In plot labels, you can use expressions, see [mathematical annotation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) :

```
 plot(1,xlab=expression("This is regular"~italic("this is italic")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To provide an string for which an HTML parser will recognise the need to render the text in Italics, wrap the text in `<i>` and `</i>`.  For example:  `"This is plain text, but <i>this is in Italics</i>."`.

However, most HTML processors will assume that you want your text to appear as-is and will escape their input by default.  This means that the special meanings of certain characters - including `<` and `>` will be "turned off".  You need to tell the processor *not* to do this.  How you do that will depend on context.  I can't tell you that because you haven't given me context.

Are you for example, writing to a raw HTML file?  (You need do nothing.)  Are you writing to a Markdown file?  If so, how?  In plain text or in a rendered chunk?  Are you writing a caption to a graphic?  (Waldi has suggested a solution.)  Etc, etc....

Comment: Thanks!...I using paste0 inside of a chunk... somethink like:

```concl <- paste0("Não existem diferenças significativas entre as médias das variávies ", var1, " e ", var2)``` 

var1 and var2 are variable names that I would like to get in italics.

Comment: And then where and when do you attempt to render your `concl` variable?  Please, please provide a [simple, self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).  Put simply, give me some code (as little as possible) that enables me to see `concl` being rendered in a way other than you want.

Comment: ok,  My Rmd is:



```{r variable selection, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
concl <- paste0("Não existem diferenças significativas entre as médias das variáveis ", var1, " e ", var2)
```
6. A conclusão do teste é: `r concl`



This needs to be output to an html file via knit.